# Android SQLite delete table not actually deleting the rows

Tags: android, mysql, ios, sql, sqlite

Hi i am trying to delete all the rows in a table by below query

```
db.beginTransaction(); // db is a SQLiteDatabase object
int deleted = db.delete("user", null, null);
db.endTransaction();
```

I am getting n number of rows deleted in the table. But still rows exist in the table. Anything wrong in my delete call?

Comment: Try with `DROP` table....

Comment: Try this : 

    String deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE;
    db.execSQL(deleteSQL);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `setTransactionSuccessful` to commit all the changes done to the database, before calling `endTransaction`:

```
db.beginTransaction();
int deleted = db.delete("user", null, null);
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
```

Source (Android developer reference):

> The changes will be rolled back if any transaction is ended without being marked as clean (by calling setTransactionSuccessful). Otherwise they will be committed.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
public int delete(String tableName) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    int x = db.delete(tableName, null, null);
    db.close();
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

`db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name");`

Where db is a reference to a SqliteDatabase object.

Answer (score 0):

When we install the app the database file is recreated in the /data folder. The problem may occour due to recreation of database even after deleting the files.

Check if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
String query="delete from "+tablename;

SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();

db.execSQL(query);

Log.d("msg","deleted");
```

Comment: Next time remember to format your post properly before posting it. (: